# Лямбды в Android

Tags: java, android, lambda

Изучил лямбды. Использую их в Android приложении:

```
swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.swipe_refresh_layout);
    swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(() -> {
        if (isOnline()) {
            //mArticleAdapter.clear();
            SimpleRss2Parser parser = new SimpleRss2Parser(postFactum, getCallback());
            parser.parseAsync();
            if (mRecyclerView == null) {
                new ShowArticles().execute();
            }

            swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
        }
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
        }
    });
```

Получаю ошибку "lambda expressions are not supported at this language level". Android Studio сама предлагает решить проблему. Исправляю, вроде ошибок нету, но на Runtime получаю туже ошибку. Возможно ли использовать лямбды в Android?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Да, возможно. Вам нужна поддержка лямбд для Android. Есть [библиотека](https://github.com/shtankoksu/gradle-retrolambda) на GitHub. Подключаете ее в проект и работаете.